# How does one send a list of column names as a variable into dplyr's mutate?

Tags: r, dplyr

DataFrame, "data1", has column names "standard", "voffset", "temp", "loop_div".  I am able to create a new column, "legend", using mutate:

data2=mutate(data1,legend = paste(standard,voffset,temp,loop_div, sep="_"))

However, I would like to create a variable to contain the column names to use in mutate, instead, because the columns to use will change depending on the dataframe I am using.  I have tried using a single quoted string as follows:

legend_cols='standard,voffset,temp,loop_div'
data2=mutate(data1,legend = paste(legend_cols, sep="_"))

This produces "standard,voffset,temp,loop_div" for every value in the legend column of the dataframe, data2$legend.  This is because I've lost the reference to the actual columns.

How can I create column references in my legend_cols string variable, or is there a better approach to mutate with a variable set of columns?

Comment: You should read the `dplyr` vignetted [on non-standard evaluation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html).

Comment: `DF %>% mutate(legend = paste(names(.), collapse = "_"))` creates a new column named `legend` in which every row has the concatenated names of the columns of `DF`.

Comment: Thank you @G.Grothendieck ! The names(.) was what I needed to get the column names within the mutate function. Now I see that . can represent the entire DF